# Closure/Interior of a Set

Tags: general-topology

> Is it true that $\overline{int(A)}= int(\bar{A})$ ?

I feel as if this is not true if I consider if $A$ is a nowhere dense set since then by definition, the RHS is empty but am unclear as to what the interior of a nowhere dense set is to proceed with the LHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side is a closed set, and the right-hand side is an open set. This means, in general, they are not the same. Take an open ball $A$ in $\mathbb R^n$ for instance. The left-hand side is the closed ball. The right-hand side is the  open ball.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the LHS is closed (by definition) and the RHS is open (since they are the union of all points which are in an open neighborhood).